# Submit with a jQuery Prompt

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, submit

Let's say I have a fairly generic jQuery Prompt that asks me to rename an element and then tells me what I entered:

```
$(function () {
$("#rename").click(function () {
    jPrompt('Please Enter a New Name:', 'Enter new name...', 'Rename Prompt', function (r) {
        if (r) {
            alert('You entered ' + r);
        }
    });
});
});
```

But the element that I wish to rename is stored on a database on the server, which means that I need to run a server-side script to rename this element. I assume that this means that I need to use a submit, just like on a form. I've found some information about a .submit() jQuery function [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) but I do not entirely understand how it works. If anyone could let me know how I would make a submit and then run a server-side script that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("#rename").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jPrompt('Please Enter a New Name:', 'Enter new name...', 'Rename Prompt', function (r) {
            if (r) {
                $('input[name="NewName"]').val(r.Name);
                $.post('@Url.Action("Edit", "TheController")', $('#hiddenform').serialize(), function(response) {
                    // response = ActionResult
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

1. Use `Url.Action` to get a correct URI
2. Use prevent default to block default action
3. Return some kind of JSON from the MVC3 action to indicate success/failure.
4. Place a hidden `<form>` somewhere and fill it with the information to post

Comment: Wow, that was fast... thanks a bunch, I completely forgot about hidden forms.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use AJAX to send a request from JavaScript to a server-side script. Look into the [jQuery API documentation on AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for more information.

The following jPrompt callback will issue a HTTP POST request to a server-side script, passing `id` and `newName` arguments along with the request. In PHP, you would then retrieve these with `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['newName']`.

```
function (r) {
    if (r) {
        $.post("rename.php", {
            data: {
                id: somethingToIdentifyTheElement,
                newName: r
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Successfully renamed the element!
                // If your server-side script returned something interesting,
                // you can find it in the response argument
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone could let me know how I would make a submit and then run a
>   server-side script that would be really appreciated.

for this you need to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) function, in order to call the serverside function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'YourController\yourAction',
  type:'post'
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```